# trying to check record exist in table -Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
declare
ac_num accounts_table.account_id%type:=1;
begin
IF EXISTS (SELECT account_id FROM accounts_table WHERE account_id= ac_num) THEN
dbms_output.put_line('exists');
else
dbms_output.put_line('not exists');
end if;
end;
```

Getting  error like this

> ORA-06550: line 4, column 4:
> PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' may be used inside a SQL statement only
> ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> 2. ac_num accounts_table.account_id%type:=1;
> 3. begin
> 4. IF EXISTS (SELECT account_id FROM accounts_table WHERE account_id= ac_num) >THEN
> 5. dbms_output.put_line('exists');
> 6. else

I need to check 1 in already present in `accounts_table` if then print "exist" else "not exist".

Comment: Why tag SQL Server is you are using Oracle???

Comment: couldn't get you? i m trying to check record exist or not? how to to that? in oracle?

Comment: You have tagged "SQL Server" which is a completely different database to Oracle...